# How to render a dynamic generated jsp page(not saved on server) in android webview, which is returned in a post API hit

Tags: android, jsp, webview

Thanks for paying attention..

I am working on an Android application in which I am going to hit a post web service. In the service response, I received a .jsp content in the form of string. This jsp content also may have some .css and java script code.
So .jsp response may be anything with themeing and all.
I am using a Webview to load this .jsp response.

Note :  I am not able to load jsp with the help of url as I already told that the jsp page generated dynamically and not saved on server too. This jsp content is just returned in post web service and destroyed then.

I am able to load this jsp page basic page content if I am going to set

```
webview.enableJavaScript(false);
```

But if I am going to enable java script in my code to load jsp page it just stuck and nothing is load.
We can render a jsp page if we have url but I am stuck on this requirement.

Help is appreciated..

Comment: It's very unclear what you really get back from the server; I guess an HTML page (mime type `text/html`). If it works with java script disabled but not with java script enabled there seems to be a problem in the contained javascript code.

Comment: If I am loading this page in Computer chrome online editor, it works fine and in iOS devices, it also loading nicely. So I think its not a problem Dear Henry. Yes its HTML code in response.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked:

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://www.example.com", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

Note : 
"https://www.example.com" is your website base url and html is the string html response received in post API hit.